# multi location document in mongo odm

Tags: mongodb, location, geospatial, doctrine-odm

since 1.9 mongo supports multi location documents http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-MultilocationDocuments

we are using doctrine mongo odm and this functionality is vital for our project.

does anybody know how to create a multi location document in mongo odm?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-referencing this with the same question you asked in [mongodb-odm issue](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/400).

I don't believe ODM needs any special support for this, just as it doesn't for [multi-key indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) of array fields. Try defining a geo index on the field containing your array of points. Also, I'd note that [ODM's geo documenation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/geospatial-queries.html) suggests using an embedded object to hold coordinates. MongoDB will support that, but an array (i.e. `[x, y]`) is preferred.